# CocoaPods Swift Unresolved Identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to create my own CocoaPod. I have updated cocoapods to the latest version (`sudo gem install cocoapods`) and then ran this: `pod lib create MySwiftLibrary`. I set the language to Swift, used the Quick testing framework, added an auto-generated example project, and did not include UI tests. I then navigated to MySwiftLibrary/Example and ran `pod install`.

That way, my example project was configured. I opened the *.xcworkspace in the auto-generated example project, navigated to `Pods -> Development Pods/MySwiftLibrary/MySwiftLibrary/Classes/ReplaceMe.swift` and added the following code:

```
public class ReplaceMe : UILabel {
    public func testMe() -> String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

I ran `pod install` again, and in the example part of the project (`MySwiftLibrary -> Example for MySwiftLibrary/ViewController.swift`) I added the line `import MySwiftLibrary` and modified the `viewDidLoad` method such that the file looked as follows:

```
import UIKit
import MySwiftLibrary

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = ReplaceMe()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I ran `pod install` and `pod update`, just to be sure, but when trying to build the project, I get the following error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'ReplaceMe'`. What am I doing wrong? This is literally the barest of bare-bone project modifications.

**UPDATE**: I just found out the issue, and it is something a responded could not have guessed. I have anonymized the name of the pod. In reality, I didn't call the pod `MySwiftLibrary`, but `MyLibrarySwift`. (`MyLibrary` is still not what it really was). I tried making that same pod again and again, and it didn't work. But then I had the idea to try a name that did not end with `Swift`, and it instantly started working.

Comment: Did you build the project once you added the pods?

Comment: I did, @Dershowitz123, but I just found out what the issue was. Please see my amended modification.

Comment: Does your pod use any other dependancies?

Comment: No, none. I did not make any modifications other than the ones described in the question.